# How to save GPS data with a taken photo in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, metadata, photosframework

I am developing a camera application which can be used to take pictures and save them in a separate album. I used photos framework to save images and now I need to save GPS data (location where the picture is taken) with the picture (may be in metadata). I searched for any method to do this thing using photos framework but I failed, I couldn't find anything related. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the peace of code I used to save pictures

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:capturedImage];

    placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];

    photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:Album options:nil];

    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:Album                                                assets:photosAsset];

    [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    if (success)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the latitude & longitude. Have you tried the location property of PHAsset class?

Comment: I can access exif data but couldn't find a way to save.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller
Does this help?

Comment: Using AssertLibrary it is possible. I know that. I want to do it using photos framework since AsserLibrary is deprecated from ios 9 or 8 as i remember.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462112/ios-8-photos-framework-access-photo-metadata

Comment: I will try this Jarora. Thanks for your responce (Y)