# How can I retrieve the metadata of PHAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I am getting the user selected image in `PHAsset` format. and I want to get the image path.

My goal is to upload the image to Firebase and based their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files?authuser=0), I need to have the image path.

I found from researching that I need to get the metadata of the image first and store it in local file and then I can retrieve the URL. Is it correct?

My question here is (If the above correct), how can I get the metadata of `PHAsset` image format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURL from PHAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025487/nsurl-from-phasset)

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462112/ios-8-photos-framework-access-photo-metadata

Comment: @OzgurVatansever I came across that URL, but it didn't help me as it is too old and no longer works with swift 4

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrive the image file Path from your PHAsset address then use this function:

```
[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new] completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
        }];
```

asset=PHAsset *asset